# Does not print, loop and array error

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, methods

I have to create an Array with 10 rows, each having 6 columns (it is supposed to be like a seating chart for a boat). Also, I have to assign passengers names to the spots and print the seating chart. I have to fill the array by requesting input of passenger name, and the desired seat (row and column).  If the seat is available, assign to passenger. If the seat is already assigned, I have to request another row and column. I have to keep repeating this input process until the row value input is a negative number.

After that, I have to print the passenger seating chart, listing any unassigned seats as “empty”.

However, my program is not working the way I want it to. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        String [][] Seats = new String [10][6];

        int row, column;
        String name;

        do {
            System.out.println ("Please enter your name");
            name = kb.nextLine();

            System.out.println ("Please enter a row or input a negative number to stop");
            row = kb.nextInt();

            if (row < 0) {
                SeatingChart (Seats);
            }

            System.out.println ("Please enter a column");
            column = kb.nextInt();

            if (Seats [row][column] == null) {
                Seats [row][column]= name;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry this seat is alredy assigned");
            }
        }
        while (row >= 0);
    }

    public static void SeatingChart (String Seats[][])
    {
        for ( int r = 0; r< Seats.length ; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c< Seats[r].length; c++) {
                if (Seats[r][c]==null) {
                    System.out.print("empty");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(Seats[r][c]+ " ");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you got - wrong result, partial result, error or exception?

Comment: @AMY it just stops asking questions

Answer (score 0):

is it what you want?

```
//change kb.nextLine()
name = kb.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put all of this in another else statement:

```
System.out.println ("Please enter a column");
column = kb.nextInt();

if (Seats [row][column] == null)
    Seats [row][column]= name;

else
    System.out.println("Sorry this seat is alredy assigned");
```

I'd also add

```
System.out.println ("Please enter your name");
name = kb.nextLine();
```

into the aforementioned else statement, either before or after asking for the column.

The other thing I would change is the way that the seats are displayed. I'd suggest having them in a 10 x 6 format. You could do so using an extra if statement. Adding a space after "empty" will also help readability. Something like the following:

```
for ( int r = 0; r< Seats.length ; r++)
            for (int c = 1; c<= Seats[r].length; c++)
            {
                if (Seats[r][c-1]==null)
                    System.out.print("empty ");
                else
                System.out.print(Seats[r][c-1]+ " ");

                if((c % 6) == 0) {
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }

            }
```